# Why is my VBA ComboBox blank until I type

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I created a simple `UserForm` `ComboBox` with a list of items:

```
Private Sub CourseComboBox_Change()
CourseComboBox.List = Sheets("Course Lists").Range("G2:G15").Value
End Sub
```

When I run the `UserForm` the drop down list appears empty until I type something. At this point the full list displays for me to choose from. Is there something I'm doing wrong that makes the text in my `ComboBox` not show up until I type?

I tried adding `CourseComboBox.ListIndex = 0` (a previous solution on here), which had no effect.

Comment: Might it be... because this code is in a `Change` event?

Comment: Like what @BigBen said, your code really needs to be in a `Userform_Initialize()` event - that way your combobox is populated when the userform starts up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're loading the contents of the Combobox when the combobox changes (i.e. the Combobox' `Change` event) where you should be loading the combobox on the `UserForm_Initialize()` event handler instead.

Try moving this line:

`CourseComboBox.List = Sheets("Course Lists").Range("G2:G15").Value`

To here:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CourseComboBox.List = Sheets("Course Lists").Range("G2:G15").Value
End Sub
```

And delete the other `CourseComboBox_Change()` event code.

Comment: `Form_Load()` is VB.net. I guess you meant `UserForm_Initialize()`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I edited to `_Initialize`, but in my (modal) forms I always put that kind of initialization in `_Activate` - the `_Initialize` handler runs before the object reference is returned to `form` in `Set form = New UserForm1`. But then again, I'd have some `Model` class pull the `Courses` list from the sheet *before* the form is even instanciated, and then since we can't be sure OP's form is actually being instanciated, recommending `_Initialize` is the only way to ensure the initialization runs only once per instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @SiddharthRout. It's been a little bit since I've worked with userforms in Excel.

Comment: So, the method worked a treat for two of my three combo boxes. Thanks!  The one it didn't work for, relies on the user choice of one of two radio buttons to populate with the correct list; If MethodOptionButton1.Value = True Then
LocationComboBox.List = Sheets("Course Lists").Range("C4:C10").Value
ElseIf MethodOptionButton2.Value = True Then
LocationComboBox.List = Sheets("Course Lists").Range("C2:C3").Value
End If This one now doesn't load any list at any time, thoughts?

Comment: @EdMerry in that case it sounds like you want to have a conditional set of values in another ComboBox. You can add that `If` statement in the `_Change()` event of whichever control you need to have the ComboBox depend on (just don't have it change `LocationComboBox`'s values in its own `LocationComboBox_Change()` event, otherwise you'll have the same problem as before.